# how to search for the particular string in file name in batch file programming?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have to search a particular folder having `*.txt` files, but the name of the file contains some dates like `20120712`, `20120713` so on.

I would like to search for files having particular dates or greater and move them to another  folder. How can I search for the filename containing a certain date or its greater using batch?

Comment: You could search for filenames with `FOR...(*)` or `FOR /R` and test then if it contains a date in your range

Comment: Side-note: please use punctuation in your future questions.

Comment: We need to know more about how the file names are formatted. If the filenames follow a particular template then it might not be too difficult. But if the date can be randomly embedded anywhere within the file name then it may be very difficult, perhaps impossible.

Comment: @dbenham the date can be extracted with Sed and passed for parsing. Shouldn't be _that_ difficult...

Comment: @Eitan - A 3rd party Windows compatible version of sed definitely makes the task much simpler, though I generally try to stick with native batch capabilities. But the point I was making was that there might be multiple 7 char numeric strings within the filename. Without a good name template spec, there is no way to know which chars to extract.

Comment: @dbenham of course. I'm just throwing ideas on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set SEARCH_DIR=c:\temp\source
set TARGET_DIR=c:\temp\target
set DATE_THRESHOLD=20120720

REM ***
REM *** NEED TO MODIFY REGEX ACCORDINGLY (THIS REGEX EXPECTS THE FILES TO BE CALLED YYYYMMDD.TXT).
REM ***
for /f %%F in ('dir /b %SEARCH_DIR%\*.txt 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.txt"') do (
    call :PROCESS_FILE "%%F"
    )

endlocal

goto END


:PROCESS_FILE

set PF_FILENAME=%1
set PF_FILENAME=%PF_FILENAME:"=%

REM ***
REM *** EXTRACT THE NUMERIC PART FROM THE FILENAME.  THIS WILL NEED MODIFYING IF YOUR FILENAME FORMAT IS NOT YYYYMMDD.TXT.
REM ***
set /a PF_YYYYMMDD=%PF_FILENAME:~0,8%

echo Processing file [%PF_FILENAME%]...

REM ***
REM *** CHECK DATE.
REM ***
if %PF_YYYYMMDD% LEQ %DATE_THRESHOLD% (
    echo File not old enough - skipping.
    goto END
    )

REM ***
REM *** MOVE FILE.
REM ***
echo Moving file....
move "%SEARCH_DIR%\%PF_FILENAME%" "%TARGET_DIR%"
if exist "%SEARCH_DIR%\%PF_FILENAME%" (
    echo ERROR : Failed to move file.
) else (
    echo File moved successfully.
)

goto END


:END
```